# rdesktop remote connect windows server 2012r2, device redirection doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdesktop

I use rdesktop to connect to a windows server 2012r2 from my linux box. it worked well. but it doesn't work when I redirected my local directory /home to the server.
My command:

```
rdesktop  -a 24 -r disk:home=/home -u test 192.168.1.110
```

I could connect to the Windows server. but I cannot see the directory in my remote computer.
Running `net use x: \\tsclient\home'` works when I connect to windows 7, but it yields this error in windows server 2012r2:

`system error 87 has occure

     the parameter is error`

I have no idea what to do.

I have turned off the firewall and deployed the RemoteFX to enable device redirection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that specifications for RDP (MS-RDPEFS) have changed. In specific Windows versions, you also have to forward audio in order to get disk forwarding to work.